# Null Rows' Existence Due to Join Table By Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am struggling with `Group By` and `Null`, as below.

I have two tables like below

```
Table : 1 accountmast       
companyID   accname             category    
102         PURCHASE ACCOUNT    Purchase Account    
102         LOCAL PURCHASE      Purchase Account    
102         SALES ACCOUNT       Sales Account   

Table: 2 ledger     
companyID   name                debit   credit
102         PURCHASE ACCOUNT    4742.3  
102         LOCAL PURCHASE      51106   
102         SALES ACCOUNT               8010
102         SALES ACCOUNT               4330000
102         PURCHASE ACCOUNT    5480000
```

And I have queried as below:

```
select  
case    
when a.catagory ='Purchase Account' then    
l.name  
end as PurchaseAccount, 

case    
when a.catagory ='Purchase Account' then    
sum(coalesce(l.debit,0))-sum(coalesce(l.credit,0) ) 
end as PurAmt,  

case    
when a.catagory = 'Sales Account' then  
l.name      
end as SalesAccount,    
case    
when a.catagory = 'Sales Account' then  
sum(coalesce(l.credit,0))-sum(coalesce(l.debit,0) ) 
end as SalesAmt 

from ledger l join accountmast a    
on l.companyID=a.companyID  
and l.name = a.accname  
where l.companyID=102   
and a.catagory IN('Purchase Account','Sales Account')   
group by l.name,a.catagory
```

And the result is:

```
Purchase Account    PurAmt          Sales Account   SalesAmt
LOCAL PURCHASE      51106.00         NULL           NULL
PURCHASE ACCOUNT    5484742.30       NULL           NULL
NULL                NULL            SALES ACCOUNT  4338010.00
```

And the requirement is:

```
Purchase Account    PurAmt           Sales Account   SalesAmt
LOCAL PURCHASE      51106.00         SALES ACCOUNT   4338010.00
PURCHASE ACCOUNT    5484742.30
```

What is the solution?.

If I use `Group By` then it allows `Null` value to associate tables' columns.

If I use `MAX`, `MIN` then it shows the single records. What do I have to do?

If anyone has better solution please suggest.

Comment: SQL will return a table -what do you want in the 4th position?

Comment: Capitalizing Every other Word is so XVI Century.

Comment: @Mark, Sorry I didn't get it 4th position, which 4th position?.

Comment: @Mark, If no value then null else value

Comment: @Quassnoi, I didn't get you?.

Comment: @mahesh: in modern English, only proper nouns are capitalized. You don't need to write "Result", "Requirement" etc: this sounds like a old manuscript.

Comment: @Quassnoi, Ok Got it. Also suggest which word I have to replace With "Result" And "Requirement" which will help me to edit the question.

Comment: @mahesh: "result" and "requirement", without capitalizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  am.category, l.name,
                CASE am.category WHEN 'Purchase Account' THEN amt ELSE -amt END
        FROM    accountmast am
        CROSS APPLY
                (
                SELECT  name, SUM(COALESCE(credit, 0) - COALESCE(debit, 0)) AS amt
                FROM    ledger l
                WHERE   l.name = am.accname
                        AND l.companyId = am.companyId
                GROUP BY
                        name
                ) l
        WHERE   am.companyId = 102
        )
SELECT  l1.name, l1.amt, l2.name, l2.amt
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
        FROM    q
        WHERE   category = 'Purchase account'
        ) l1
FULL JOIN
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
        FROM    q
        WHERE   category = 'Sales account'
        ) l2
ON      l2.rn = l1.rn
```

Comment: There is an error"No columns specified for column 3 of q" where you have to specify the columns name Like "amt" on Line "CASE am.category WHEN 'Purchase Account' THEN amt ELSE -amt END" "as amt"

Comment: Your query shows sale amt figure same as purchase amt figure. It's not showing sum() well on columns.

Comment: It's Corrected your query in MS Sql-2008 but I am using Sql-2005 there is no option for sql-2005. Your corrected query on ms sql-2008 is nothing return on my sql-2005, It's return Null, I am Confuse?. Otherwise your suggested Link is very much useful.

Comment: @mahesh: the query will return same values on the same data on both engines. Copy the fiddle to `2005` and see.

Comment: here I have provide new post for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This is not an answer It is a reference for Quassnoi consideration.**

Here certain correction I have made for your consideration.

```
WITH    q AS
(
SELECT  am.catagory, l.name,
CASE am.catagory WHEN 'Purchase Account' THEN Amount ELSE -Amount     END as Amount -- Here I provide the column name and alter the Column
FROM    accountmast am
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT  name, SUM(COALESCE(debit, 0) - COALESCE(credit, 0)) AS Amount --Reverse the sum function which is oppose of yours. And your's shows the value in minus.
    FROM    ledger l
    WHERE   l.name = am.accname
    AND l.companyId = am.companyId
    GROUP BY
             name
    ) l
    WHERE   am.companyId = 102
)
SELECT  l1.name as PurACC, l1.Amount as PurAmt, l2.name as SalACC, l2.Amount as SalAmt -- alter the columns for Binding Purpose.
FROM
    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
        FROM    q
        WHERE   catagory = 'Purchase account'
    ) l1
FULL JOIN
    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
        FROM    q
        WHERE   catagory = 'Sales account'
    ) l2
ON l2.rn = l1.rn
```

The above changes is Important otherwise your answer remain as incorrect and throws an error check it.